# Oracle10G Query: NOT IN VS EQUALS

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

We are having issues with a Oracle query (Query1) which is taking too long to execute:

Query1:

```
Select * 
from table 
where status NOT IN ('IN_PROGRESS', 'SUCCESS', 'FAILURE');
```

--> 2mins for a table size of 200,000 bringing records of size 4000.

Query2:

```
Select * 
from table 
where status ='WAITING';
```

--> Returns in 2 seconds for the same volume.

It would be great if some one could explain why this happens.

Comment: Are there only 4 distinct values for `status`?  What are the two query plans?  Is there a histogram on the column?  Are the cardinality estimates of the two plans different?

Comment: Because Query1 has to do a full table search, and Query2 can simply do an indexed search.

Comment: yes those are the only 4 distinct status. The query1 which is currently in our application code is used by Spring-JBDC-Inbound-adapter to feed it in to the Spring-Integration channels. The query2 is suggested by our DBA to improve the performance.

Comment: Check out the execution plans and you'll see why

Comment: can we change the execution plan of the Query1 to return the records quickly.

Comment: @ElectricLlama - "sargable" is exactly the phrase I was trying to imply in my response.  Thank you!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Answer (score 3):

You might have an index on the status column. (please verify).

If you think of an index in a phone book, and someone says 'find me the phone number for Mr Waiting' then you zoom along the first letters until you find W and find him and then you know you are finished. If someone says 'find me the phone numbers for everyone whose last name is not Mr Waiting', then the only way to logically complete this is go through the entire index until you have checked every entry to verify it is not 'Mr Waiting' (you might be smart enough to stop when you reach W but you still have to do more work)

In other words, `=` is more 'sargable' than `NOT IN`. You might want to research sargable. You might also want to take a look at the query plans as suggested. You might not be able to make sense at first but practice makes perfect.